# How can we determine the order of zero for $\xi$?

Tags: number-theory

Riemann Xi function, denoted as $\xi$, is given by $\frac{1}2s(s-1)\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)\zeta(s)$. I know this function is considered as entire, by canceling out the poles at $0,1$ by multiplying $s(s-1)$, but it seems off to me because I cannot literally plug in $0$ and $1$ for $xi$, because I cannot write $\zeta(0)$ since it doesn't exist. Is "cancellation" of poles implied here in this expression?

Also, how can I determine the order of zero for $\xi(z)$ at z=0? This is evaluated as zero at zero, so I think the order is at least 1. But since the pole was cancelled, is it just zero? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\xi(s)=\frac{1}{2}s(s-1) \, \pi ^{-\frac s2} \,  \Gamma \left(\frac{s}{2}\right)\,\zeta (s)$$ is perfectly defined at $s=0$.

Using series expansions around $s=0$, we have
$$\pi ^{-\frac s2}=1-\frac{1}{2} s \log (\pi )+\frac{1}{8} s^2 \log ^2(\pi )+O\left(s^3\right)$$
$$\Gamma \left(\frac{s}{2}\right)=\frac{2}{s}-\gamma +\frac{1}{24} \left(6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2\right)
   s+\frac{1}{24} s^2 \left(-\gamma ^3-\frac{\gamma  \pi ^2}{2}+\psi
   ^{(2)}(1)\right)+O\left(s^3\right)$$
$$\zeta(s)=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} s \log (2 \pi )+$$ $$\frac{1}{48} s^2 \left(24 \gamma
   _1+12 \gamma ^2-\pi ^2-12 \log ^2(2)-12 \log ^2(\pi )-24 \log (2) \log (\pi
   )\right)+O\left(s^3\right)$$
Putting all together
$$\color{blue}{\xi(s)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4} s (-2-\gamma +\log (4\pi ))}+$$ $$\color{blue}{\frac{1}{32} s^2
   \left(-16 \gamma _1+8 \gamma -6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2+2 \log (4 \pi ) (-4-2
   \gamma +\log (4 \pi ))\right)+O\left(s^3\right)}$$ This truncated expansion reproduces quite well the $\xi(s)$ function for $0 \leq s \leq 1$.

Just to givr an idea
$$\int_0^1 \Big[\xi(s)- \text{expansion}\Big]^2\, ds=2.81\times 10^{-9}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The one thing I'm wondering is... $\zeta(0)$. Could you please explain... since $\zeta=\sum \frac{1}{n^s}$ and so $\zeta(0)$ blows up ($1+1+1+1+\dots$), why are we able to write zeta in terms of taylor series? I mean even if we know that $\frac x{x}$ converges to $1$ as we approach $0$, we don't say $0/0=1$, write? And in the above case, whatever infinity we have for the rest of the term, if we plug in $z=0$, it must be zero..?

Comment: @jk001. $\zeta(0)=-\frac 12$ as far as I know. Have a look at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function